# BAD Redirect invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key

Tags: api, authentication, linkedin-api

I have tried most of the things which I found on google, but did not get solution for this error. I don't know why I'm getting this error. Following are the details about what I did in configuring the linkedin APP.

OAuth 2.0
Authorized Redirect URLs: http://connect.fckme.org/auth0.com/login/callback

URL while Login with Linked in is: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?type=web_server&client_id=75rlnmz5qgket3&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fconnect.fckme.org%2Flinkedin_login&response_type=code&scope=&state=ccbe2c881c5826c06ac4769ba72a620d .

Please help me with this, Every help and comment will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 4):

You have registered `http://connect.fckme.org/auth0.com/login/callback` as the authorized redirect URI for your application in LinkedIn, but you're passing `http://connect.fckme.org/linkedin_login` (url-encoded) in the `redirect_uri` parameter in the authorization request. That last URL does not match the configured setting and thus is refused by LinkedIn.

So make sure that you pass `http://connect.fckme.org/auth0.com/login/callback` in the `redirect_uri` parameter in the authorization request to LinkedIn.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hans z, Thanks for realizing that to me. It worked after I changed the URI to linkedin_login. I wanted to give vote to your answer but, I'm not eligible for giving the vote.. Will do it soon when I'm eligible.

Comment: you could still accept the answer, that'd be nice already ;-)